# X by Y checkboard using OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am attempting to create a X by Y checkerboard (by this, I simply mean that I could set any size for X and Y) using OpenGL ES 2.0, but I'm wondering how I go about creating the pattern.

I have already got the MVP matrix working well (presently I'm just using a solid colored rectangle), it correctly renders appropriate to the screen, centered and in full view (and each box [-created a couple test boxes] is square, regardless of the over-all size).  The world coordinates are simple 1x1 spaces for each grid space, and the view and projection matrices bring it into perfect view.

What I can't work out is applying that checkerboard pattern.  I considered first using a single rectangle as I am now, and applying a fragment shader, but I couldn't work out how to make that work given that the grid could be any number of spaces in either direction (and no longer in world coordinates by that point).  I also considered creating a background and then adding a colored square every other space, but that seemed resource intensive for what should be a pretty simple job.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use mod function and remainder to select the white or black
and poke this into the color.

Look for some examples at the famous [GLSL Sandbox](http://glslsandbox.com/) site.

See also figure 1.2
http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/TNM084-2012/proceduraltextures.pdf

> `mod(floor(10.0*s) + floor(10.0*t), 2.0)`